# Why does this unvoiced ほ sound become a voiced ぼ sound?

Tags: pronunciation, rendaku

I've seen a couple videos of a Japanese translation of the song Twinkle Twinkle Little Star. This Japanese version is titled 「きら きら ぼし」. However, star is 「ほし」.

Why is the ほ sound voiced in the title?

Example of this: http://blogs.transparent.com/japanese/twinkle-twinkle-little-star-in-japanese/

Comment: It's called  [rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku)

Comment: You have been saying "origami" all your life, no?  Even though the Japanese word for "paper" is "kami" and not "gami"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku

> Rendaku (連濁?, lit. "sequential voicing") is a phenomenon in Japanese morphophonology that governs the voicing of the initial consonant of the non-initial portion of a compound or prefixed word. In modern Japanese, rendaku is common but at times unpredictable, with certain words unaffected by it.

*Rendaku* is the changing of voicing that, in practice, is usually the addition of a *dakuten/tenten* to the first syllable of a word contained within a compound or phrase.

As mentioned above; rendaku occurs commonly but is unpredictable, in that there isn't any fit-all rule that determines when it applies.
However, rendaku commonly appears in words involving the *noma* iteration mark (々) indicating repetition of the prior character, such as in *hitobito [人人/人々、ひとびと, not hitohito]* and *samazama [様様/様々、さまざま, not samasama]*

In your example, *きらきらぼし* is considered a single phrase in that *きらきら* is a modifier describing *ほし*.